# Access FlowLayoutPanels' controls' method

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Let's assume I have a `FlowLayoutPanel` called `panel1`, with `control1`, `control2`, `control3` inside it.
Each control have a method `.doSomething()` or a stored variable `.name`.
How do I access these?

Something like:

```
panel1.Controls[0].doSomething();
string name = panel1.Controls[0].name;
```

My code:

```
public partial class ChatItem : UserControl
    {
        public string username, description, mainUser; /// <summary>
        /// mainUser este utilizatorul care foloseste in prezent aplicatia
        /// </summary>
        MySqlConnection basicConnection, chatUpdater, msgSender;

        #region Properties

        [Category("Custom Properties")]
        public string user
        {
            get { return label1.Text; }
            set { label1.Text = username = value; }
        }

        [Category("Custom Properties")]
        public Image profilePicture
        {
            get { return pictureBox1.Image; }
            set { pictureBox1.Image = value; }
        }

        public Image dot
        {
            get { return pictureBox2.Image; }
            set { pictureBox2.Image = value; }
        }

        #endregion

        public void doSomething()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("something");
        }

    }
```

I want to access `.doSomething()` and `description`.How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should iterate over [Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controls?view=netframework-4.8) property, but control should be casted to your type to use fields/methods specific for your class

```
foreach(var control in panel1.Controls) 
{
   if (control is ChatItem chatItem) // to ensure the casting can be done
   { 
       string description= chatItem.description;
       chatItem.doSomething();
   }
}
```